# My Xbox One controller suddenly stopped working on PC

Tags: controllers, xbox-one, hardware, windows

Sorry, English isn't my first language. Please let me know if you didn't understand something and I will try to explain it in another way.

So, until Saturday (2 days ago) my Xbox One controller was working perfectly on my Windows PC.

On Sunday, I turned on my PC, and **the LEDs on the controller wouldn't stop blinking**. It usually is completely stable. When I turn the PC on, it usually vibrates for a short period of time as well, and it didn't vibrate this time.
I tried updating the driver (automatically and manually on Windows), restarting the PC multiple times, unplugging and plugging it as well. Nothing really helped.

Any tips?

Comment: Hey there, couple of questions:  

1. Is it a wireless controller with a battery pack or wired only/no battery?
2. Is the "blinking" described a pattern or intermittent? If it is the latter and your controller is wired, this may indicate an issue with your controller cable or the micro USB port on the controller.

Comment: Hey, thanks for Answering!
1: It is wired, a non removable wire, actually. (It is a knup controller, and I don't expect you to know what brand this is)

2: It blinks slowly, non stop. Like, 1 second on, 1s off.

3: If that's the problem, than I am screwed... As I said, the wire can't be removed.

Oh, and the controller's model is KP-5130.

Comment: It sounds like an aftermarket controller. I have no judgement on what you buy, but unofficial peripherals are generally unreliable, not to mention built and behave differently. I strongly recommend editing your post to mention that it is not an official controller.